# Host reveal.js slides (.html) [Jupyter notebook export] as webpage on non local server

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook, html, reveal.js

I am currently working on a Jupyter Notebook.
I managed to export it as reveal.js slides (.html) and host it on my local server. I used the following command line in the terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert <mynotebookname>.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

It generates a `<mynotebookname>.slides.html` file and opens it in my browser, where I can navigate properly through the slides (as seen in this example on https://revealjs.com).

However, if I upload this file to my 'web' folder at my University's server (where I usually upload any html files that I want to see as a webpage) I get a single scrollable page with the content of my notebook. It doesn't present the same slide perspective as on the local server.

I would like to make it available as a webpage so that I can share it with other people.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to find the solution by using the command below:

```
jupyter nbconvert <mynotebookname>.ipynb  --to slides --reveal-prefix "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js@3.6.0 "
```

This way the generated slides.html file will render the slides correctly in your browser, whether the file is on your local machine as a standalone file or at a webserver/github/bitbucket being displayed as a webpage.

I wasn't aware that when not using `--post serve` it is necessary to point the reveal-prefix to some reveal.js library available at a CDN (content delivery network). Apparently `--post serve` does that for you. As an alternative it is also possible to point to a local reveal.js library.

Here are some links that helped me reach this solution. They contain some additional commands that may be useful while converting your notebook to slides.

https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/157

https://medium.com/learning-machine-learning/present-your-data-science-projects-with-jupyter-slides-75f20735eb0f

https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/docs/source/usage.rst

http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/using-a-local-revealjs-library-with-your-ipython-slides.html